# Can't restore a SQL Server database from a backup file - Error: 102

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to restore a SQL Server database, I get:

"An exception occured while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
Incorrect syntax near 's'
Unclosed quotation mark near character string ". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:102)"

I am not using any script, just clicking "Restore Database", selecting the file (it has no extension, by the way), and get this error.

I tried to search for a solution, but can't find anyone that had a similar problem. I would really appreciate any input!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you restoring to the same SQL Server version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to permission problem.First you need to move the *.bak file to the data-directory of the SQL-server   .. then try again..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you didn't name the directory using special characters.  For example, I named my directory `SQLDB's\` and got that error. To resolve it, I removed the ' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission issues for the SQL Server database not user. Just try to move your *.bak to the data directory where other files kept. Now repeat that process again.

If you find it helpful then, mark it as the correct answer.

Good Luck!